# Add directory before SEO keyword OpenCart

Tags: .htaccess, opencart, opencart2.x

I am developing an OpenCart website and I have to copy all products from a Woocommerce website that uses permalinks that start with /product.

Example: http://yourdomainname.com/product/productname.

I have to keep the url rewriting because the customer doesn't want to loose Google index.

Do you know how I can keep the structure and start with /product ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

have a many way to make this.
but in opencart seo_url make this structure:
yoursite.name/category/product_name(.html optional)
and have options show url without category and make just yoursite.name/product_name(.html optional).

or use any extentions about SEO PRO like that.
or use Ocstore(russian edition), this community make seo_pro for free, and work good.

or use google webmasters tools, and make redirects for all products manually.

and please next time when make question, please write your opencart version and how many products your store have.